# Problems with code in "A Swift Tour" tutorial

Tags: swift

This tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html

I'm getting an error for using the exact same code in the example. Is this my fault, and if so how/what can I do to correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you opened the link you provided, you'll see that in the tutorial `shoppingList` and `occupations` have been declared before being used:

```
var shoppingList = ["catfish", "water", "tulips", "blue paint"]
var occupations = [
    "Malcolm": "Captain",
    "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
]
```

After declaring variables, you can use them with their names directly, like this:

```
shoppingList = []
occupations = [:]
```

You declare variables using `var` or `let` (for constants), depending on your needs.

Comment: OH I see that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't allocated `shoppingList`:

```
var shoppingList: [String] = []
var occupations: [String: String] = [:]
```